# Unable to compile in laravel. Error in app.scss

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I am getting This error log when I run `npm run watch`

Laravel Version:- 5.6

Vue Js version:- 2.5.7

Here is the Error:-

```
pbdgr@DESKTOP-LRSJU17 MINGW64 /f/coding and website developing/Multipurpose vue js and laravel website/larastart (master)
$ npm run watch

> @ watch F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart
> npm run development -- --watch


> @ development F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"
 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...astart\r 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active
Webpack is watching the files…

 10% building modules 1/2 modules 1 active ...\larasta 10% building modules 1/3 modules 2 active ...astart\r 10% building modules 2/3 modules 1 active ...\larasta 10% building modules 2/4 modules 2 active ...astart\r 10% building modules 3/4 modules 1 active ...\larasta 10% building modules 3/5 modules 2 active ...modules\ 10% building modules 4/5 modules 1 active ...\larasta 10% building modules 5/6 modules 1 active ...node_mod 10% building modules 5/7 modules 2 active ...tart\res 10% building modules 6/7 modules 1 active ...tart\res 10% building modules 6/8 modules 2 active ...t\node_m 10% building modules 7/8 modules 1 active ...tart\res 10% building modules 7/9 modules 2 active ...de_modul 10% building modules 7/10 modules 3 active ...es\asse 10% building modules 7/11 modules 4 active ...rces\as 10% building modules 7/12 modules 5 active ...ts\js\c 10% building modules 7/13 modules 6 active ...les\vue 10% building modules 8/13 modules 5 active ...les\vue 11% building modules 9/13 modules 4 active ...les\vue 11% building modules 10/13 modules 3 active ...les\vu 11% building modules 11/13 modules 2 active ...les\vu 11% building modules 12/13 modules 1 active ...les\vu 11% building modules 13/14 modules 1 active ...es\ass 11% building modules 13/15 modules 2 active ...rces\a 11% building modules 13/16 modules 3 active ...ts\js\ 11% building modules 13/17 modules 4 active ...es\ass 11% building modules 13/18 modules 5 active ...rces\a 11% building modules 13/19 modules 6 active ...ts\js\components\ExampleComponent.vue{ parser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }. 
 11% building modules 14/19 modules 5 active ...ts\js\ 11% building modules 15/19 modules 4 active ...ts\js\ 11% building modules 16/19 modules 3 active ...ts\js\ 11% building modules 16/20 modules 4 active ...ode_mo 11% building modules 16/21 modules 5 active ...ode_mo 11% building modules 16/22 modules 6 active ...ue-loa 12% building modules 17/22 modules 5 active ...ue-loa 12% building modules 18/22 modules 4 active ...ue-loa 12% building modules 19/22 modules 3 active ...ts\js\ 12% building modules 20/22 modules 2 active ...ts\js\ 12% building modules 21/22 modules 1 active ...ts\js\ 12% building modules 22/23 modules 1 active ...rastar 12% building modules 22/24 modules 2 active ...larast 12% building modules 22/25 modules 3 active ...rt\nod 12% building modules 22/26 modules 4 active ..._modul 12% building modules 22/27 modules 5 active ...les\ad 12% building modules 22/28 modules 6 active ...odules 12% building modules 23/28 modules 5 active ...odules 12% building modules 24/28 modules 4 active ...odules 13% building modules 25/28 modules 3 active ...odules 13% building modules 26/28 modules 2 active ...odules 13% building modules 27/28 modules 1 active ...odules 13% building modules 28/29 modules 1 active ...ode_mo 13% building modules 29/30 modules 1 active ...start\ 13% building modules 29/31 modules 2 active ..._modul 13% building modules 30/31 modules 1 active ..._modul 13% building modules 31/32 modules 1 active ...start\ 13% building modules 31/33 modules 2 active ...rt\nod 13% building modules 31/34 modules 3 active ...start\ 13% building modules 31/35 modules 4 active ...ode_mo 13% building modules 31/36 modules 5 active ...e_modu 13% building modules 31/37 modules 6 active ...\node_ 13% building modules 31/38 modules 7 active ...de_mod 13% building modules 31/39 modules 8 active ...dules\ 13% building modules 31/40 modules 9 active ..._modul 13% building modules 32/40 modules 8 active ..._modul 13% building modules 33/40 modules 7 active ..._modul 14% building modules 34/40 modules 6 active ..._modul 14% building modules 35/40 modules 5 active ..._modul 14% building modules 36/40 modules 4 active ..._modul 14% building modules 37/40 modules 3 active ..._modul 14% building modules 38/40 modules 2 active ..._modul 14% building modules 39/40 modules 1 active ..._modul 14% building modules 40/41 modules 1 active ...os\lib 14% building modules 40/42 modules 2 active ...\axios 14% building modules 40/43 modules 3 active ...les\ax 14% building modules 40/44 modules 4 active ...ode_mo 14% building modules 41/44 modules 3 active ...ode_mo 15% building modules 42/44 modules 2 active ...ode_mo 15% building modules 43/44 modules 1 active ...ode_mo 15% building modules 44/45 modules 1 active ...start\ 15% building modules 44/46 modules 2 active ...dules\ 15% building modules 44/47 modules 3 active ...es\axi 15% building modules 44/48 modules 4 active ...ules\a 15% building modules 44/49 modules 5 active ...node_m 15% building modules 44/50 modules 6 active ...module 15% building modules 44/51 modules 7 active ...les\ax 15% building modules 44/52 modules 8 active ...\axios 15% building modules 44/53 modules 9 active ...module 15% building modules 44/54 modules 10 active ..._modu 15% building modules 45/54 modules 9 active ..._modul 15% building modules 46/54 modules 8 active ..._modul 15% building modules 47/54 modules 7 active ..._modul 15% building modules 48/54 modules 6 active ..._modul 15% building modules 49/54 modules 5 active ..._modul 16% building modules 50/54 modules 4 active ..._modul 16% building modules 51/54 modules 3 active ..._modul 16% building modules 52/54 modules 2 active ..._modul 16% building modules 53/54 modules 1 active ..._modul 16% building modules 54/55 modules 1 active ...odules 16% building modules 55/56 modules 1 active ...astart 95% emitting

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors     6:43:38 PM
 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Api.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)        
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)       
    at NormalModule.doBuild (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)   
    at NormalModule.build (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)    
    at Compilation.buildModule (F:\coding and website 
developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:157:10)    at factoryCallback (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:348:12)        

 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:14-266
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Api.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\bin\convert-argv.js
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js:3:14)        
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)       
    at NormalModule.doBuild (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)   
    at NormalModule.build (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)    
    at Compilation.buildModule (F:\coding and website 
developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:157:10)    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:460:10
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:172:11
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:32:11)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18
    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)       
    at NormalModule.doBuild (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:182:3)   
    at NormalModule.build (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)    
    at Compilation.buildModule (F:\coding and website 
developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:157:10)    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:460:10
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:243:5
    
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)    at loadLoader (F:\coding and website js and 
- F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js

    at iteratePitchingLoaders (F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)

website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:195:19
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11

 js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:275:15)    
    at Compilation.buildModule (F:\coding and website 
developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:157:10)    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:460:10
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:243:5
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:94:13
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:268:11
    at NormalModuleFactory.<anonymous> (F:\coding and 
website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\CompatibilityPlugin.js:52:5)
    at NormalModuleFactory.applyPluginsAsyncWaterfall 
(F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js 
and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\tapable\lib\Tapable.js:272:13)
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:69:10
    at F:\coding and website developing\Multipurpose vue js and laravel website\larastart\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:196:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the NPM module `node-sass` is missing

```sh
npm install --save node-sass
```

Comment: This didn't help even though I ran  the command .. it still says ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
          ^
      Undefined variable: "$real".

Comment: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/lib??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--5-5!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
          ^
      Undefined variable: "$real". @Shizzen83

Comment: Read your errors, you'll see it's not the same one, my answer solved it, it's just because it was not your only error. And not enough details to solve this one.